# Pointing a Picture to the Compass Line

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, digital-compass

I am using the Raw Sensor Data Sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Sensors for my Projekt.

I implemented it into my Projekt and now I need to add a picture in the shape of a circle to the Magnetic heading line.

```
<Line x:Name="magneticLine" X1="240" Y1="100" X2="240" Y2="0" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="4"></Line>
```

How can I achieve, that a Picture is Rotating with this Line?

Is it possible to add X and Y coordinaties to a Picture so it keeps the same direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're tryign to achieve but you can probably achieve what you want with a `RotateTransform` or a `TranslateTransform` depending on your exact requirements.
For more see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189037(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: well yeah this kinda the direction i want to go. let's say the picture i want to use is an Arrow. Now i need the Arrow to rotate exactly like the magneticLine. how can i achieve that?

Comment: ok i found out a way to do it. i am using Polygons instead of a Picture. now i can Rotate the Polygon with Polygon.RenderTransform.

Thanks.